# Etherchain Lost Password

Tags: go-ethereum

Hi I had created a wallet in the Etherchain but lost my 12 words passcode, due to accidently deleted them.  Is there anyway that I can get the ETH fund transfer me back?

My etherchain address is below:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x2c964fc2dee70060c19d32a458a71ea9ac6f21af

Thank you so much.
Best Regards,
Somchai

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to recover the wallet without that 12 word seed.